# What is this widget called in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, widget

I've been trying to find this widget and have no clue what it is called.
[image]

I should probably add that the arrows key (in|de)crement the values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called a [Spinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: See also [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) for a quick overview of what is available.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Both :) and yep I have, I just had to wait for the time limit to expire.

Answer (score 6):

It is called [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html), the Swing tutorial has an [overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) for all standard components.

Comment: Please start linking to the v. 7 JavaDocs.  +1 for the link to the visual guide.